# Mule retry using until successful scope during external webservice call if the service is down

Tags: mule

I am facing problem with until successful scope , the use-case as follows

mule flow contains:
inbound : http endpoint

outbound: http outbound calling external web service

i designed flow such that i defined my external web service call inside until successful scope, the requirement is that, retries need to happen if external service is down and should stop retry in between when the service is up and running

I couldn't achieve it.

Required inputs how i can acheive it and also the correct failureExpression need to be define for untillsuccessful scope.

Mule version(3.5.1) - Anypoint Studio - July 2014

Config:

```xml
<until-successful
    maxRetries="3"
    doc:name="Until Successful"
    millisBetweenRetries="5000"
    failureExpression="#[exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) ||
        exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException) ||
        exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketException)]" synchronous="true">
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        method="POST" address="http://localhost:8088/mockPriceSoapBinding"
        doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/html" tracking:enable-default-events="true" />
</until-successful>
```

Comment: Mule version, config, or we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed earlier i have tried with status code based combination on failure expression. Here the retries are happing correctly. The problem here is, if the remote service available before number of retries, still the retries are continuing and flow is not getting executed.

failure expression:#[header:INBOUND:http.status != 200]

Comment: `header:INBOUND` is super old deprecated Mule expression syntax, use MEL instead: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: hi david,we have tried with both MEL using message.inboundproperties and also with the above MEL expression

Comment: the thing is: if the remote HTTP endpoint fails, there will be no `http.status` inbound endpoint so the above expression itself may fail because of the `null` value.

Comment: Use the SET Payload to save the original payload before http       outbound endpoint. Currently the nature of until successful is when ever the retry mechanism is happening payload is getting over ride by exception . By using the set payload we can make the payload available to outbound and can achieve the retires.

Comment: I could not figure out what the final solution was, can it be incorporated into the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no `exception`, the current failure expression will NPE. Check for nullity like this:

```
failureExpression="#[exception != null && (exception.causedBy(java.net.ConnectException) || exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException) ||
```

exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketException))]"

You may need to manually escape `&` in `&amp;` depending on how you enter this expression.

Comment: Hi David ,Thanks for your reply i tried with the failure expression you have mentioned. But its not working as expected in case of external http service call is up and active in between retries. Even the service is up and running during retries of until successful scope still the retries is happening till the configured no of times. Need your inputs how it can be resolved.